# nodejs (new Date()).toJSON() returns a wrong time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the following code to get current date and time in nodejs.

```
var date = (new Date()).toJSON();
```

after converting to JSON, it returns a wrong time with a wrong timezone as below:

```
2018-01-03T11:16:38.773Z
```

but without **toJSON()** it returns the real time in correct timezone

```
Wed Jan 03 2018 14:47:12 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)
```

Comment: You need to include extra details in your question, what is you expected and actual output, aka define _wrong time_

Comment: what are the outputs?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: can you share a screenshot with this where you run these lines of code

Comment: Use `toString()` instead of `toJSON()`

Comment: why are u converting toJSON, you can use toString() if you donot want date object

Answer (score 0):

The format is different because:

> The toJSON method is a built-in member of the Date JavaScript object.
>   It returns an ISO-formatted date string for the UTC time zone (denoted
>   by the suffix Z).

What you can do:

> You can override the toJSON method for the Date type, or define a
>   toJSON method for other object types to achieve transformation of data
>   for the specific object type before JSON serialization.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/tojson-method-date-javascript)

If you want the same result you could just use toString instead of toJSON:

```
var date = new Date().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2018-01-03T11:17:12.000Z === Wed Jan 03 2018 14:47:12 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)
```

The one on the left hand side is ISO timezone and one on the right is basically the browser timezone.

`(new Date()).toJSON()` converts into ISO timezone

So a simple way to convert to string is

```
var date = (new Date()).toString();
```